# Lubuntu-desktop on Raspberry Pi 4 (4gb) 19.10 ARM64

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, gui, 64-bit

When I flash the arm64 image onto one of my Raspberry Pi 4B (4gb ram) from here (64bit version: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) and then do an install via apt of `lubuntu-desktop`, it gives me a base gnome-desktop instead. This is after the kernel fix to fix the USB ports in 64 bit. In 32bit installing Lubuntu works fine.

Full process:
Flash 19.10 server 64bit image onto Raspberry Pi 4:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
#reboot
```

Following reboot, I get a screen with a single underscore _ for a long time than a standard gnome login screen going to a gnome unity style desktop with a Xubuntu background, not Lubuntu at all.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that you should [better use `apt full-upgrade`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md) instead of only simple `apt upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the 'Ubuntu' option on the gnome login screen takes you to another page with a password field and a gear icon that lets you choose your desktop environment.